# Local variable of a c file is not getting created in stack, its GCC compiled code,

Tags: c, gcc, stack, bios, uefi

I am working in UEFI EDK2 Bios source. We created a platform related new package in the EDK2 source. I find a strange issue with the platform related code we added.

When I did source level debugging I noticed the
local variable in a C function is not getting created in stack when its compiled with GCC.

The same UEFI code when compiled with visual studio then local variable in a C function is getting created in stack.

I am executing this code on a Simulation environment where I can see the Stack Base, all segment registers, Current executing code, memory etc..

Its a multi-core system but only Boot Strap processors in enabled

Comment: Perhaps GCC put the variable in a register, or optimized it out since it wasn't being used? You fail to describe why this is a problem (and of course also fail to show any code).

Comment: Maybe it's an optimization issue? And local variables (a.k.a. *automatic variables*) doesn't *have* to be on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the C11 language specification, you'll find that it never mentions the stack or stack frames or putting variables on the stack. There is no requirment in C to put automatic variables in any kind of stack.

How the program stores automatic variables (i.e. those defined within a function scope but without the `static` keyword) is entirely up to the compiler. In olden days, most compilers created space on the system stack for arguments, the return address and local variables. In modern times, this has fallen out of favour because processors generally have lots of registers and it's more efficient to keep local variables and function arguments in registers if at all possible.

There are only two reasons why a compiler needs to store an automatic variable on the stack:

1. There are too many variables and arguments to put them all in registers
2. The function takes the address of the variable (you can't have a pointer to a register)

So gcc is probably deciding that it doesn't need to create stack space for your variable and it goes in a register. The Visual Studio C compiler always used to be notorious for being neglected by Microsoft so it is probably not so up to date with modern ideas about automatic variables.

Also, you'll find that compilers often optimise variables away. If you don't do anything useful with your variable, the compiler may decide it doesn't need it at all. For example in the following code

```
int f()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i);
    return 0;
}
```

The loop is empty, so the compiler knows it can throw it away and then it doesn't need the variable so it will throw that away too.